# Facebook App - Error Message: (#2010) This app has been restricted from uploading photos

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I recently created a facebook app that daily loads pictures with quotes on a users walls. It has been growing in users adding the app daily. We are at about 376 users. That means roughly 367 photo posts daily.  It will only grow. However today I got this error:

Error Message: (#2010) This app has been restricted from uploading photos

What might cause this issue? Am I limited to so many photos per day? I am sure other app post thousands of pictures daily so this can't be it. I am sure other users come across this issue as well. Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer. I got an email from facebook. In short I had default text included with each image. You can not do this I guess.

**Facebook wrote:**

We've placed a restriction on photos published by your app because it's in violation of Section IV.2 of the Facebook Platform Policies. This policy prohibits apps from pre-filling the caption for any photo published on behalf of a user unless the user created the content earlier in the workflow. Please note that including default text is against policy even if users are able to edit the content your app created.

Once you've removed the pre-filled content from your app, or if you think we've enforced on your app in error, you can appeal this decision.

Comment: Let's say you still need to post some information to go with the image. How would you do that? The only thing comes to my mind is to post a comment to that photo on behalf of the user. Please, suggest a solution if you did some workaround?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to appeal a decision made by Facebook's policy team, you need to go here: https://developers.facebook.com/appeal